# How is a synchronous 214 rpm motor for a 50 Hz mains possible?

Tags: motor, ac, synchronous

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_motor) *at steady state, [...] the rotation period is exactly equal to an integral number of AC cycles*. Now I have a brief description of a three-phase motor designed for 50 Hz AC mains claimed to run at 214 rpm (a 4 megawatt motor for a water pump).

So the motor has 214 rpm and the mains has 50*60 = 3000 oscillations per minute.

3000 is not a multiple of 214. How is such synchronous motor possible?

Comment: Actually 214 is very close to 3000/14.  This means there is likely a reduction of 7 going on and they rounded the result to the nearest integer RPM.  Probably the "reduction" is accomplished by multiple poles, not gears, especially at that power level.

Comment: 4MW / 214 rpm = 178250 N-m...That thing must be a beast!

Comment: @user28910: It is, its stator's diameter is about 4 meters - a human can stand inside it.

Comment: Is the motor in question a synchronous motor?  Many powerful machines, especially three-phase-powered ones where speed doesn't have to be absolutely precise, use induction motors whose actual speed will be the synchronous speed minus a "slippage" which is proportional to torque and will generally be a small fraction of the synchronous speed.  Even if the synchronous speed would be 214.29rpm, it's not hard to imagine that adding a mechanical load could slow the motor down by 0.14% or even more.

Answer (score 2):

From the same [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_motor#Synchronous_speed) page:

Synchronous speed: $$N_S = \dfrac{2\cdot 60 ×f}{p}$$

Where:

\$N_S\$ is the synchronous revolutions per minute [rpm]

\$f\$ is the mains frequency in Hz or s-1;

\$p\$ is the number of poles in the machine, this is always an even number;

\$2\$ because magnetic poles always come in pairs (except for free energy projects, these apparently found a way to create monopoles ...);

\$60\$ because there are 60 seconds in a minute.

Notice that mains frequency is in cycles per **second** and the synchronous speed is in revolutions per **minute**. So you have to convert either the speed or the frequency for equal units.

Therefore:

$$p = \dfrac{2\cdot 60× f}{N_S} = \dfrac{2\cdot60×50}{214} \approx 28$$

The number of poles must be an even number: 28 and the speed must obviously be rounded to 214 rpm (214.2857142857143........).

Comment: Then the statement that *the rotation period is exactly equal to an integral number of AC cycles* is just not correct.

Comment: The statement is correct, but the rpm mentioned isn't exact. It should be 214.285........, but rounded that comes to 214 rpm.

Comment: Well, how is the rotation period *exactly equal to an integral number of AC cycles* even if it's 214,285... ?

Comment: The number of AC cycles is the mains frequency 50 (per second), converted to cycles per minute (60 seconds in a minute) 50 × 60 = 3000 mains cycles per minute. Then divided by the number of poles in the machine (which apparently is 28) 3000/28= 214.285..........

Comment: I see, but the original statement doesn't mention poles.

Comment: That is how a synchronous machine works. It is a revolving magnetic field and magnetic fields always have two poles (north and south). The field is induced by the stator (the "house") and that field revolves with the synchronous speed by definition.

Comment: Yes, it probably would be more accurate to say that the number of pole transitions needs to be an integral number of AC cycles, not the number of full revolutions (as there may be many poles per revolution.)

Comment: @JonWatte: That looks like an actual answer.

Comment: @sharptooth because you've confused "frequency" and "period". 214.285... rpm = 1 revolution per 0.28 seconds = a period of 14 cycles (at 50Hz). Last time I checked, 14 is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to have a gearbox stepping down speed and for a two pole AC synchronous motor (or induction motor running at synchronous speed) the RPM will be 1500 on a 50Hz supply. If your gearbox steps it down 7:1 in speed you get an output RPM of 214.28.

Comment: Or a 28 pole machine?

Comment: @jippie could be!!!

Comment: @jippie: That could be an answer, but I don't really get it.

Comment: @sharptooth speed of this type of motor is \$\frac{F\times 60}{P}\$ where F is mains frequency and P is number of pole pairs. 50 * 60/14 = 214.28. But, it is more likely the motor has a speed reduction gearbox. Just noticed the MW power rating and it may indeed have 14 pole pairs.

Comment: @Andyaka: So the idea is that increasing the number of poles kind of increases the rpm of the rotor relative to the stator?

Comment: @sharptooth increasing the number of poles reduces the speed of the rotor for a given ac frequency as per the formula in my previous comment. Do you have a link to the motor?

Comment: @Andyaka: The description is not in English and not on the manufacturer's site http://www.fgup-kim.ru/go/Pump_st

Comment: Each AC cycle moves the rotor through one set of pole pairs. There may be many pole pairs for a full revolution. Think of it as a stepper motor, perhaps? Similar concept in some ways.